# How to specify which pipe to use if multiple modules exported same name pipes?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer, angular2-custom-pipes

In my project, I'm using **NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule** & **TranslateModule**(@ngx-translate/core). Both packages export `translate` pipe.

The `translate` pipe from **NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule** returns `Promise<string>`.
And, the `translate` pipe from **TranslateModule** returns `string`.

In a module I have to use both to show some pdfs. Now, how do I specify which pipe to use?

Answer (score 0):

imports can also be renamed

```
import { translate as translate1 } from "./NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule";
import { translate as translate2 } from "./TranslateModule";
```

Comment: I am importing the modules like this: `NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule, TranslateModule.forChild()` in my projects module, not importing the pipes themselves directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```js
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { translate as translate1 } from "./NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule";
import { translate as translate2 } from "./TranslateModule";

@Pipe({ name: 'translate1' })
export class Translate1Pipe extends translate1 { }

@Pipe({ name: 'translate2' })
export class Translate2Pipe extends translate2 { }
```

Declare the Pipes in Modules and use it inside template

```html
<h1>{{'TEST'| translate1}}</h1>
<h1>{{'TEST2'| translate2}}</h1>
```